# Laravel "->where(like) issue"

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this code

```
$users = array();
$users_to_add = User::all()->where('unit', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->unit.'%');
```

But i get nothing on $users_to_add. The like doesn't work. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all()` actually runs a query to get all users.  Therefore, your `where()` call is on the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) (PHP), not the Query Builder (SQL).

You'll want to use `get()` but make sure you declare your query conditions prior to calling it.

`get()` will execute the query, with your defined conditions, and return a collection of results.

```
User::where('unit', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->unit.'%')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't knew why it wasn't working. Thank's a lot :)